# Dynamically create sub collection for api gateway resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform0.12+

Given url `/customers/{customerId}/accounts` or `/customers/{customerId}/accounts/{accountId}`

Is it possible to have the resources created dynamically?

I do not want to have duplicated code. I was planning to use some sort of map or list to manage this. Is it even possible?

Sample (hardcode):

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "customers" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.my-api.id}"
  parent_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.my-api.root_resource_id}"
  path_part = "customers"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "single-customer" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.my-api.id}"
  parent_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.customers.id}"
  path_part = "{customerId}"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "customers-accounts" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.my-api.id}"
  parent_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.single-customer.id}"
  path_part = "accounts"
}

//----
// GET
//----
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "get-customers-accounts" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.my-api.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.customers-accounts.id}"
  http_method = "GET"
  authorization = "NONE"
}
```

Something like this:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "var.resource.name" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.my-api.id}"
  parent_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.<previous resource id or root id if is root>}"
  path_part = "<current value>"
}
```

Comment: You're using HCL1 syntax there. Can you confirm you need a 0.11 compatible answer (and also tag the question with `terraform0.11`) or instead replace the syntax with HCL2 syntax please?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I am just giving an example. I am using 0.12

Answer (score 0):

Resource names cannot be dynamic.

A common solution is to define the resource once and use the `count` variable to dynamically create multiple instances based on a list, e.g. (untested, example code in the same HCL1 syntax you've provided):

```
locals {
    list_of_maps = [{
        "api_id" = "some_id",
        etc...
    },{
        "api_id" = "some_id",
        etc...
    }]
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "gateway" {
    // will create a resource for every element inside list_of_maps 
    count = "${count(local.list_of_maps)}"

    // every iteration will take the corresponding map and pull variables from it using "lookup" 
    rest_api_id = "${lookup(element(local.list_of_maps, count.index), "api_id")}"

    etc...
}
```

You can also wrap the resource above inside a `module` and pass the `list_of_maps` as a variable, allowing further reuse of this resource definition.

Comment: Hmmmm.. but the `parent_id` depends on the previous `aws_api_gateway_resource. gateway.id`. How are we able to get it, if we are doing it this way?